# Erro no uso de alias e read no ShellScript

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, terminal, shell-script

Estou tentando criar um comando no .bashrc do ubuntu, porém estou tendo um problema, estou tentando criar uma pasta com a variável digitada na hora de chamar o alias, porém esta dando erro. Quando abro o terminal ele já pede o nome da pasta, mas não quero isso, quero digitar o comando em qualquer lugar. O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

```
#comando digitado no terminal
username@username:~$ pasta nome_pasta
```

Onde **pasta** é o nome do alias, e **nome_pasta** é a variável obtida pelo read.

Se estou fazendo isso me maneira errada qual seria o melhor método para se ter um comando como o citado acima?

meu code esta assim:

```
# arquivo .bashrc
function CreateFolder(){
    if [ -n "$USER" ]; then
        alias pasta='mkdir $name'
        read name
    else
        echo "Error :/"
    fi
}

CreateFolder
```

desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como existe uma chamada a função `CreateFolder` no final do arquivo `.bashrc`, ele já está executando essa função logo após o login.

Segue um exemplo de função que pergunta para o usuário o nome da pasta,
caso ela não seja informada no parâmetro (criado no `.bashrc`):

```
pasta () {
        # Se o nome da pasta estiver definido no parametro
        if [ $1 ]; then
                # atribui diretamente a variavel PASTA
                PASTA=$1;
        else
                # Senão, pergunta para o usuário
                # qual o nome da pasta a ser criado
                echo "Qual o nome da pasta? "

                # Lê a entrada do usuário e guarda na variável PASTA
                read PASTA
        fi

        # Cria a pasta
        mkdir $PASTA
} 

# Não colocar a chamada para pasta aqui
```

Após a execução:

```
~/teste$ pasta teste1
~/teste$ ls
teste1
~/teste$ pasta
Qual o nome da pasta?
teste2
~/teste$ ls
teste1  teste2
```

<sub>testado com Debian 4.2.3-2 e GNU bash - 4.3.42</sub>

Comment: Obrigado, tua resposta me ajudou muito, não imaginei que seria tão fácil assim lol.

Answer (score 0):

Se você só precisa que `pasta` crie um diretório, então só precisa disso no `.bashrc`:

```
alias pasta='mkdir'
```

No momento que você digita `pasta uma_pasta` o Bash substitui `pasta` por `mkdir` antes de executar o comando.